# Impossible integral appears when trying to solve $t^{\beta} u_{t} - u_{xx} = f(x,t)$.

Tags: definite-integrals

I have done a reduction of this equation: $t^{\beta} u_{t} - u_{xx} = f(x,t)$ to an ODE and this integral seems to be impossible:

$$\int_{0}^{T} e^{\frac{-2 \lambda t^{1- \beta}}{1- \beta}} dt$$

I've tried Wolfram, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It's already well known that $\int e^{x^2} dx$ doesn't have an elementary form, so this integral definitely won't.

Comment: … except in special case like $\beta=1$ (trivial) or $\beta=\frac12$ (easy). Perhaps there are other special cases, but the general case is hopeless.

Comment: What do you mean by 'impossible integral'?